# How to map values from one column to multiple fields?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Say I use Open CSV and have something like:

```
public class MyDto {
    @CsvBindByName(column = "AFBP")
    String placeholderA;
    @CsvBindByNames({
            @CsvBindByName(column = "ABCD"),
            @CsvBindByName(column = "AFEL")
    })
    String placeholderB;

    @CsvBindByNames({
            @CsvBindByName(column = "ABCD"),
            @CsvBindByName(column = "ALTM")
    })
    String placeholderC;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "placeholder A = " + placeholderA + ", placeholderB = " + placeholderB + ", placeholderC = " + placeholderC;
    }
}
```

After deserializing

```
var csv = "AFBP,ABCD\nthis is A,this is B and C";
```

I got

```
placeholder A = this is A, placeholderB = null, placeholderC = this is B and C
```

rather than what I need:

```
placeholder A = this is A, placeholderB = this is B and C, placeholderC = this is B and C
```

### Question

Is there a way, using this library or similar (providing support for annotations), to deserialize the CSV that a one-column-to-many-fields mapping is possible?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, this is *not* possible, at least with [OpenCSV](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/index.html) version 5.7.1. *Yet, this might change with future releases.*

The reason originates from the way how OpenCSV registers a Beans/Pojos field to column mappings via the [`HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.html). This is used by default for `CsvToBeanBuilder`:

> This builder is intelligent enough to guess the **mapping strategy** according to the following strategy:
>
> 1. If a mapping strategy is explicitly set, it is always used.
> 2. If CsvBindByPosition or CsvCustomBindByPosition is present, ColumnPositionMappingStrategy is used.
> 3. Otherwise, `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy` is used. This includes the case when `CsvBindByName` or `CsvCustomBindByName` are being used. The
>    annotations will automatically be recognized.

Internally, the class [`HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java) will call `registerBinding(..)`. In this context, the columnName of a Pojo (here: `MyPojo`) is used as a key for the mapping info in `fieldMap`.

Sadly, the current implementation does not check, in [line 168](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java#l168), if a mapping is already present for a key (eg, `ABCD`). Thus, it will overwrite the first bound field `placeholderB` with a new binding for `placeholderC`. As a result, the parsing will only recognize that it should map values from the *csv* input to the field **`placeholderC`**, as you observed.

*Side node: I tested your code and can confirm the output as given in your question.*

The only idea that comes to my mind:

- Write your own implementation of a headers (to) column name strategy.
- Start by extending from [`HeaderNameBaseMappingStrategy`](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/HeaderNameBaseMappingStrategy.html). This way you could handle existing field-to-column mappings for multiple occurrences correctly.
- Obviously, you need to register your custom, or multi-field strategy with the [`CsvToBeanBuilder#withMappingStrategy(..)`](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanBuilder.html#withMappingStrategy-com.opencsv.bean.MappingStrategy-) method.

More consequently, you could [open a change request](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/feature-requests/) to support the desired behavior. This way, the existing mapping strategy could be improved to cope with such a requirement brought up by your question here.

Currently, no other options seem to exist.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation! I ended up writing my own solution with Apache Commons CSV, but in spare time I'll try to add a CR for Open CSV :)